# Change root directory for gitlab CI

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to implement Gitlab CI on my repository. I have already set up the runner on Windows and configure the `.yml` to work with a Maven project. The problem is that I have the folders `Domain` and `Front-end` in the root of the repository. Is there a way to change the root so the `.yml` could be able to find the `pom.XML` file which is in the domain folder?

When I run it, it says that it couldn't find the pom files.

> [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/builds/motomine/web). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.

So I think changing the root folder might solve the problem.

Comment: Copy the exact error string and paste it here.

Comment: The error that I get is this one:

Comment: [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/builds/motomine/web). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.

Comment: can't you just add "cd place/to/project" in the command ran in build.yml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to change the directory. You can point maven to the directory which contains the pom. In your `.yml` file:

```
...
- mvn -f Domain
```

From the maven documentation:

> -f,--file : Force the use of an alternate POM file (or directory with pom.xml)